# How to find path to "data" programmatically in Java for Android?

Tags: java, android

I have a hard coded path to my directory on my phone for an Android Application. Android Studio complains that the path should be found programmatically. How do I code this so that it will find the path for any Android phone?

Code:

```
myInput = new FileInputStream("/data/data/com.myandroid.app/databases/data");
```

Comment: Use `getDatabasePath()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the path by `context.getDatabasePath(DataBaseHelper.dbName)`

OR, to the files directory:

`context.getFilesDir()`

Comment: Then something like this should work? dbPath = context.getDatabasePath(dbName);
OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(dbPath.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: Yes, although I'm not too sure of your context.

Comment: Or this one? InputStream myInputs = new FileInputStream(directory.getPath() + "/data");